# how to deploy struts2 eclipse web application on remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to check deploying procedure of my struts2 web application developed using eclipse juno on local tomcat server. I want to deploy it to a remote host like 000webhost. Can you provide me any information how to do that?
well, I run my application by typing

```
 http://localhost:8080/Struts2starter/
```

on browser I want to run it by typing

```
 http://myapp.com/Struts2starter
```

like something on browser. I wanted to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can deploy a Java application in 000webhost. For example, you can deploy on Google App Engine. Here is an example of how to do that: http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-struts-2-example/

Comment: thanks for the answer pigueiras. I didn't use google app engine when I develop the application. still can I use google app engine to deploy my application

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server in question. Most servers provide some kind of remote deployment using manager applications / rmi connectors / whaever else exitic means , and eclipse can work with most of them.   But of course it needs to be configured  on both sides in order to work.   Be more specific about your server config, and you will surely get proper answer